# Reemplazar un caracter de una cadena y mostrar la cadena final con espacios incluidos

Tags: c++, array

Básicamente mi código esta listo, el unico problema es que cuando voy a mostrar la cadena final modificada, solo me muestra la primera palabra (Cuando encuentra un espacio ignora el resto) yo se que mi programa deja de contar cuando se encuentra con "\0" y tambien se que el espacio cuenta como "\0" ademas del ENTER.

Quisiera saber alguna solución para este inconveniente, yo soy nuevo en esto del c++ y sé que mi error debe ser una tontería. Este es mi código:

```
void reemplazo(char *v, char c1, char c2)

{

    int i;

    for (i=0;v[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if (*(v+i)==c1)
        {
            *(v+i)=c2;
        }
    }

}

int main ()

{

    char palabra[20];
    char a,b;
    int i;

    cout << "Ingrese palabra: ";
    cin >> palabra;
    fflush(stdin);
    cout << "Ingrese caracter a reemplazar: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Ingrese nuevo caracter: ";
    cin >> b;
    reemplazo(palabra,a,b);
    cout <<"resultado: ";

    for (i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
         cout<<palabra[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola Francisco, bienvenido. Solamente para entender bien, ¿Lo que quieres es poder leer más de una palabra y luego reemplaza un caracter por otro en todas ellas?

Comment: Hola Francisco, ¿puedes explicar la razón de porqué tienes un ciclo `for` que haga 20 iteraciones? `for (i=0;i<20;i++)`

Comment: El caracter `0x20` (Espacio) es muy diferente de `0x00` (Null), no son considerados iguales, pasa que estas utilizando `cout y cin` con un puntero a un arreglo de caracteres. ¿Por qué no utilizar `std::string`?

Comment: @JYass: Si, eso es exactamente lo que quería hacer.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave : Ese ciclo for lo estoy usando para mostrar individualmente todos los caracteres de la cadena final, es una de las cosas que me pidieron hacer.

Comment: @NaCl : Me habían pedido estrictamente que no use string (Es para practicar otros métodos de ingreso) Y en cuanto a cin y cout, me di cuenta de mi error, se que tendría que haber usado gets() o cin.getline(). Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: @FranciscoFJM Me imaginé que iba a ser por algúna restricción de ejercicio :P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como ya mencionaste, el problema es que directamente solo se está leyendo una palabra. La siguiente [instrucción](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) (enlace en inglés) debería resolver el problema:

```
cout << "Ingrese palabra: ";
cin.getline(palabra, 20);
```

Y yo quitaría la instrucción:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

`fflush` solo puede utilizarse con streams de salida, como `stdout`, el uso con `stdin` es **indefinido**, y aunque en algunos compiladores puede funcionar, no es indicado su uso así.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, el error era ese (Usar cin en vez de cin.getline). Fue un error de novato =)

Answer (score 3):

programando en C++ te sería más útil dejar de usar funciones o estructuras de C para hacer el programa más simple y fácil. Por ejemplo, usando `strings`, pasaje por referencia (con el `&`), y abstraerse con el `cin` o el `cout` que se encargan de escapar los caracteres que te están trayendo problemas.

Acá te dejo de como sería el programa en C++ usando todo lo que mencioné:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void reemplazo(string &v, char c1, char c2)

{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < v.length(); i++)
    {
        if (v[i] == c1)
        {
            v[i] = c2;
        }
    }

}

int main ()

{

    string palabra;
    char a,b;
    int i;

    cout << "Ingrese palabra: ";
    cin >> palabra;
    cout << "Ingrese caracter a reemplazar: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Ingrese nuevo caracter: ";
    cin >> b;
    reemplazo(palabra,a,b);
    cout <<"resultado: " << palabra << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No siempre el código más largo es el mejor( y más en un lenguaje de programación como c++), aquí una solución corta e interactiva haciendo uso de la librería `string`, no tendrás problemas con los espacios.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

   string str;
   char ca, new_ca;
   cout<<"ingrese una cadena de texto: ";
   getline(cin, str);
   cout<<"ingrese el caracter a cambiar: ";
   cin>>ca;
   cout<<"ingrese el nuevo caracter: ";
   cin>>new_ca;

   for(int i =0; i<str.length(); i++){
      if(str[i]==ca){
          str[i]=new_ca;
      }
   }
   cout<<str<<endl;
   
   return 0;
```

}